# Unpack vector into function arguments

Tags: r, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I have a function with four parameters, e.g.

```
fun <- function( x, a, b, c ) {
    sin( x * a ) * exp( -x * b ) + x * c
}
```

I'd like to convert that into a function with three arguments provided as a vector, fixing the first (to some `df$X` in this example). The following obviously works:

```
fx <- function( args ) {
    fun( df$X, args[ 1 ], args[ 2 ], args[ 3 ] )
}
```

How do I wrap this process into a function *for any number of trailing function parameters*, returning the function `fx` above? Pseudocode:

```
fixVector <- function( f, vec ) {
    function( args ) {
        f( vec, magic_unpack( args ) )
    }
}
fx <- fixVector( fun, df$X )

fx <- fixVector( fun, 1:10 )
fx( 1:3 )
# [1]  3.113881  6.016654  9.000350 11.999746 14.999956 17.999998 21.000001 24.000000 27.000000 30.000000
```

What's a suitable definition for `magic_unpack()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building upon the hint by Roland, a possible implementation of `fixVector` is

```
fixVector <- function( f, vec ) {
    function( args ) {
        do.call( f, c( list( vec ), as.list( args ) ) )
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
fun <- function( x, a, b, c ) {
  sin( x * a ) * exp( -x * b ) + x * c
}

fx <- fixVector( fun, 1:10 )
fx( 1:3 )
# [1]  3.113881  6.016654  9.000350 11.999746 14.999956 17.999998 21.000001
# [8] 24.000000 27.000000 30.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for the saddest SO experience yet.

Comment: I don't see what's sad. You got an answer (which should make you rather happy), but didn't like a tiny aspect of it (for unknown reasons). You are free (and obviously able) to change that in your private code.

Comment: Look at it this way: I was rather happy with your answer, and changed a "tiny aspect" of it to reflect the requirements given in the question. You didn't like that (for unknown reasons), reverted the edit and basically rejected further collaboration. I had to publish the content of my edit by myself and was "rewarded" with a downvote. Be that as it may -- let's move on.

Comment: There is no unknown reason for me reverting your edit. I told you why. I want to promote best practice in my answers. You are expected to adapt answers to your specific needs anyway. What I object to is you reposting my answer with a trivial edit that introduces (what I see as) bad practice. Note that answers on SO are not only written for the question poster but for everyone.

Comment: Very well. Then please provide more specific information about the issues regarding my definition of `fixVector`. Please note that I cannot use your code directly, as it does not give me a suitable function object to pass around.

Comment: The issue is that you rely on lexical scoping. You'll learn that's not advisable once you've run in your first serious scoping issue. Apparently you have additional requirements not provided in your question which makes this an xy problem. There is at least a good chance that a solution without scoping is possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137455/discussion-between-mkluwe-and-roland).

Answer (score 5):

I'd use `do.call`:

```
x <- 1:10
a <- 1:3

fun <- function( x, a, b, c ) {
  sin( x * a ) * exp( -x * b ) + x * c
}

fixVector <- function( f, vec, args) {
  do.call(f, c(list(vec), as.list(args)))
}

fixVector(fun, x, a)
#[1]  3.113881  6.016654  9.000350 11.999746 14.999956 17.999998 21.000001 24.000000 27.000000 30.000000
```

Comment: After reading your answer I realized that I had to clarify my question. Please see my edit and the usage example at the end of my code. I'd like having `fixVector` to *return* a function.

Comment: Made an edit to your code to make it a better fit to the question, now that I've understood that the `args` argument to `do.call` does not need to have a `names` attribute, and accepted the edited version as an answer afterwards.

Comment: I've rolled that back (partially). You should pass `args` as a parameter. Do not rely on scoping.

Comment: No, that does not work for me. I need the result of the call to `fixVector` to be a function of one argument as I have shown in my edit. And as R supports lexical scoping and closures, I don't understand your comment saying "Do not rely on scoping". Please consider to undo your rollback, perhaps correcting any scoping error in my code.

Comment: Show why you believe that and I might show you an alternative. As it is, I won't change my answer.

Comment: Believe *what*?

Comment: That you "need" a function with one parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137410/discussion-between-mkluwe-and-roland).